# Adobe animate animation export/publish to android device

Tags: android, animation, jquery-animate, adobe

The animation does not show in my A30s samnsung mobile

What is the workflow recommende?

I already spent more than 20 hors and am none the wiser

I tried the Export and Publish options related to HTML/JavaScript option
but nothing apppears on the browser in the phone